# Criar Grafos com TSimpleGraph

Tags: delphi, grafo, componentes

Estou precisando criar grafos na interface do meu programa, 
a única solução que encontrei foi o [TSimpleGraph](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/simplegraph/). Tentei rodar o programa que vem no arquivo ZIP, porém dá erro que está faltando o componente `TSimpleGraph`.

Já adicionei ao programa o arquivo chamado `SimpleGraph.pas`

O exemplo do elastic nodes funciona, porém o outro (editor) não.

Não sei o que fazer, não sei se existe mesmo esse componente e como adicioná-lo (Penso que seja algo como o TeeChart).

Comment: Qual versão do delphi esta utilizando?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro da pasta que você baixou, na raiz veio os arquivos:

```
DELPHIAREA.INC
SimpleGraph.dcr
SimpleGraph.dcu
SimpleGraph.pas
SimpleGraph.res
```

Coloque onde está o `.DPR` do seu projeto, acredito que assim resolva.